# How to pass two lists contained into a model from angular to web.API (.net)

Tags: c#, angular, webapi

I'm trying to pass data from angular 9 to the api controller, two lists inside a model but in web.api side (backend) both lists are coming null (I did a console.log before send the data to the webapi and it's with data)

angular model class:

```
export class UploadData 
{
public lstUploadFiles: any[];
public fileList: File[];
}
```

component:

```
ud = new UploadData();

upload() 
{
const filesData = new FormData();
this.fileList.foreach((f) => filesData.append('certificates', f));

this.ud.lstUploadFiles = this.lstUploadFiles;
this.ud.fileList = this.fileList;

//request
this.uploadFiles = this.service.uploadFiles(this.ud)
 ................
....................
}

uploadFiles(files: any): Observable<ApiResponse> {
console.log(files); // here all is ok, object full with data
return this.http.post<ApiResponse>(this.apiUrl +  "Upload/", {files}, {withCredentials: true})
.pipe(map(model =>{
return model;
}),
catchError(error => {
this.handleError(error);
return throwError(error);
})));
}
```

dotnet side:

model:

```
public class FileUploadDTO
{
public List<File> fileList {get; set:}
public List<ReportDTO> lstUploadFiles{get; set;}

}
```

controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Upload")]
public ReportResposeDTO UploadFiles([FromBody] FileUploadDTO input) 
{
//here input.fileList is always null as well input.lstUploadFiles
}
```

And the problem is that input.fileList as well input.lstUploadFiles are always coming null to the controller... any idea?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue, the problem was in uploadFile method within angular component, when doing the http.post, the parameter "files" is between {} like { files }, after removing both { } the parameters are coming to the controller with no issues! {} is used when you want to pass multiple parameters.